# DOM manipulation on a cloned node

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a query related to DOM manipulation. I am performing some operations on the DOM nodes in a web page by cloning the entire document node and then performing the operations on the cloned copy.

One particular operation that I am performing on the DOM is changing the 'src' attribute of the 'img' tags. When I do that, I see a 404 error (404 (Not Found)) in the console for that page in the browser. The path I am setting is not present but since I am performing the operations on the cloned copy, I assumed that it should not show any error. Am I doing something wrong here? Is there a way to avoid this error from being displayed?

The code snippet is provided below:

```
//code snippet

var doc = document.documentElement.cloneNode(true);
var allNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName('*');

//for loop to interate through the node

//When an img node is found
node.src = "some_image.png";
```

Comment: I can't see why it should'nt load. Because 
`var img = new Image(); img.src = "aa.png"`
also loads a image, even though the image is not appended on the DOM. (This approach is often used in HTML5 Canvas usages)

Comment: Reading between the lines, is "some_image.png" some kind of placeholder you know doesn't exist?

Comment: @Juhana Yes. The image will be downloaded by another app and made available in the path.

Comment: Then TryingToImprove's answer is the correct one -- the browser tries to download the image as soon as the `src` attribute is set or changed. You need to make sure the image exists before setting the attribute.

Comment: @Juhana Ok. But if I load the page at a later time when the image is present in the path, it should load correctly right? This error will not have anything to do with it?

Comment: No, the `img`-tag will not have a listener to the path and try to automaticaly reload the image.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, I will ignore this error. Is there a way to do some error handling to keep the error from showing up in the console like say a try catch block or something of that sort?

Comment: The error comes because you get a 404-error (file not found), it is not a JavaScript error. If you set the `src` to a file that do not exists, and then create the file, the `img` have to be refreshed somehow

Comment: @TryingToImprove Thanks. Got it. When I am loading the file at a later stage, I would be loading it after the file is downloaded so there would be no issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

I can't see why it should'nt load. Because var img = new Image(); img.src = "aa.png" also loads a image, even though the image is not appended on the DOM. (This approach is often used in HTML5 Canvas usages)

Even though the image is added to the path after the src is defined, the image will not be found, because the browser will only send 1 request for the file.